# vsftpd permissions trouble

Tags: permissions

So, I got my Raspberry Pi 2 yesterday, installed nginx, php and vsftpd.
nginx was running, PHP files were processed and served, I could connect to FTP, so I thought everything is fine and left it there.

Today, I decided to start NetBeans and do some work, but ultimately run into problems with FTP.

#### I can

- connect to FTP using the default `pi` user without any problem
- create new files

#### I can't

- manipulate existing files via FTP (created via bash or FTP under the `pi` user)
- nginx/php can't access files created via FTP

`vsftpd.log` doesn't really provide any useful insight into this (`550 operation failed`).

nginx logs `Unable to open primary script: /home/pi/www/index.php (Permission denied)"`, as if the user running the process had no rights to read the file (nginx is running under `pi`, though).

In my `vsftpd.conf` file, the only thing I changed is `write_enable` to `YES`, all the rest is default.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi corner of the Stack Exchange. Is that `ftp` or `sftp` - how do you authenticate a remote login?  It does sound like a permissions issue BTW.

Comment: It's `ftp`, to authenticate I simply use the default `pi` user with my local password.

Comment: The reason I asked was that some systems lock down/disable ftp because the login process sends the username and password unencrypted (same as telnet) whereas tunnelling it over ssh (I think that is what sftp is!) is regarded as safe. For anonymous ftp this is not an issue for downloading public files (no authentication, or anonymous as user name and email address as password) and may be OK for uploading NEW files to an "upload" area, but overwriting or other arbitrary operations on existing files will probably not work.  Mind you it is years since I used ftp so I may have that wrong...! 8-)

Comment: Does that php file need to be *executable*, not just readable?

Comment: Personally if net beans will allow it (long time since I used it) I would ignore FTP as its insecure and just use sftp, which runs over ssh.  However, you do seem to have some permissions issues.    Where are you trying to write to?  What folder?  What are the permissions and ownership of that folder. Some visual ls -la might help the diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're working on `/var/www` and its subdirectories. If not, simply change `/var/www` to the correct directory (in you case, `/home/pi/www/`). I recommend you use the default `/var/www` and move your files over there.

Not sure how `pi` got write permissions there but here are some pointers:

- When you create files using `pi`, it will be owned by `pi`.

  - nginx usually uses `www-data` user, so that's why it can't read it. It also can't modify it.
- Likewise, when something is owned by `www-data`, depending on the permissions, `pi` cannot modify it. That's why you can't modify files.

---

There are multiple fixes for that, depending on your preferences. Here's how I do it:

1. Add `pi` to the `www-data` group using the command `sudo adduser pi www-data`
2. Add `www-data` to the `pi` group using the command `sudo adduser www-data pi`
3. Change the permission of the directory and everything in it so that it's  readable and writable by the group. Use the command `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www`.

   - Since user `pi` is part of `www-data` group, doing this allows the pi to modify files.
   - Since user `www-data` is part of `pi` group, this allows nginx to read files created by `pi`.
   - Confusing? This is because users `www-data` and `pi` have their own groups also named `www-data` and `pi`.
4. Make sure everything in the folder is owned by `www-data`.

   - `sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www`

Comment: Thank you, after adding the uses to the groups, it looks like everything is fine now. Is there any reason I should use the default `/var/www` instead of `/home/pi/www`. If I had multiple users, then using the home folder of one of them might not be the best, but I plan to work on it by myself and mostly use it for myself. Is there any other reason than convention?

Comment: @ROAL Nothing too specific. It's just standard practice in my point of view.

Comment: @ROAL If you're planning on having multiple users, what you're doing right now is the right way to do it.

Comment: I meant it more like having multiple users working on the same project. In that case, `/var/www` would probably be better, with `/home/username/www` being their "personal" project. Though for now I'm far from anything like this.

Comment: @ROAL Mmhmm. Just settle on what works for now.